# split NSString into Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am just learning Core Data.

I am trying to split a NSString into Core Data.

So far I have a string like this:

```
NSString *testStr = @"Sam,Milton Keynes,01234567890";
```

And am splitting that into an Array like this:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    array = [testStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then putting that into Core Data:

```
newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"phone"];
```

This works fine for the testStr I am using, but I want to be able to have a string with multiple records, and split that into Core Data - example of string want to use:

```
NSString *testStr = @"Sam,Milton Keynes,01234567890|Hannah,Milton Keynes,021654768431|Adam,Broughton,42445454542";
```

I can do what ive done above, then split that array further, but my question is: How do i do this and store into Core data?

any help much appreciated

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need first split the sting on `|` and the loop thru the array.
Then just insert you original code:

```
NSString *testStr = @"Sam,Milton Keynes,01234567890|Hannah,Milton Keynes,021654768431|Adam,Broughton,42445454542";

NSArray *personArray = [testStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];

for(NSString *person in personArray) {
   NSArray *array = [person componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:[array objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"phone"];
}
```

PS, don't alloc an array if you if you are going to fill it later with an other instance of NSArray:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    array = [testStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Here you just leaked a NSArray.

Comment: Great thanks! that works! only error in the code you gave me was: you used testStr for array, instead of person. thanks for the tip on leaking the array also!